# Wordpress - Custom Taxonomy Rewrite URL

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, taxonomy

How can I rewrite the URL of a custom taxonomy (taxonomies are already registered from theme)?

Actual URL: domain.com/doctor/dentist/?llocs=peje  (llocs=peje is location, where peje is location name)

What I want if it's possible:
domain.com/peje/doctor/dentist/ or
domain.com/doctor/dentist/peje

If my question is not clear, please feel free to ask me more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a rewrite rule while registering a taxonomy. Try with this code -

```
  register_taxonomy('type', 'mytest', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'          => 'Types'
    ,   'singular_name' => 'Type'
    ,   'search_items'  => 'Search Types'
    ,   'edit_item'     => 'Edit Type'
    ,   'add_new_item'  => 'Add New Type'
    )
,   'hierarchical' => true
,   'query_var'    => true
,   'rewrite'      => array('slug' => 'mytest/type', 'with_front' => false)
)); // type taxonomy
```

Comment: The taxonomies are already registered, I just need to rewrite the URL.

Comment: Please check the line of code for rewrite the slug - 

'rewrite'      => array('slug' => 'mytest/type', 'with_front' => false)

Comment: The taxonomy is already registered like this (just a snippet of it): https://pastebin.com/raw/s08RpkZB

Comment: You need to change go Settings > Permalinks and set the "post name" option and save. 
and Try with this code -  

$locslug = '/peje/doctor/dentist';

register_taxonomy('listing_location',array('post'), array(
            'hierarchical' => true, // false for insert new tax when inserting post
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'=> true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $locslug ),
));

Comment: Yeah, but the location is a dynamic value. I want ?llocs='location' become /location/doctor/dentist. So when location is peje, /peje/doctor/dentist/